# How to compute the CTFT using matlab?

Tags: matlab, signal-processing, fft

I'm trying to find a factor using matlab that requires me to compute the Fourier transform of an input signal. The problem was stated to me this way:

```
fbin = 50HZ
0 <= n <= 1999
alpha = F {Blackman[2000] . cos[-2pi . fbin . n/2000]} (f)

where F is the Continous Time Fourier Transform operator.
```

My matlab code looks like this:

```
blackman_v = blackman(2000);
signal_x = cos(-2 * pi() .* fbin * (0:(1999)) ./ 2000) .* blackman_v';
fft_real = abs(fft(signal_x, 2000));
alpha = fft_real(51); %51 is the bin for 50hz => or {(f * N/Fs)+1}==51
```

My problem is that I'm supposed to get a value of around 412 for 49hz but I get about 250 (I'm actually verifying some previous results). Did I wrongly translate the problem? I've been battling for quite a while and I really don't see anything wrong here. Thought the value a 50Hz (430) is ok.

Would really appreciate any hint!

---

EDIT

```
blackman_v = blackman(2000);
signal_x = cos(-2 * pi() .* fbin * (0:(1999)) ./ 2000) .* blackman_v';
alpha = abs(freqz(signal_x , 1, 2*pi*50/10000))
```

Do you know what the freqz is? I read matlab doc and it is still not to clear in my head.

Comment: As I looked at this problem, I see more questions.

The function `F {Blackman[2000] . cos[-2pi . fbin . n/2000]} (f)`, is this supposed to be a convolution of the two functions, or point by point multiplication?  The FFT from Matlab has no scaling on it, even the length of points scaling.  Are you trying to find the power spectral density?  It seems strange that the absolute value would be of much use, but that's just my 2 cents.

Comment: actually an excellent point, I was wondering about convolution vs point by point. The instructions I have are quite confusing. It says that "The DFT bloc calculates the 2000 points DFT of the 50hz bin of the Blackman windowed input signal".

Comment: It is a buffered signal on a DSP, so bin is the buffer containing the sampled 50 hz signal. I'll filter the signal with the blackman window.

Comment: I decided to check with the dev. as I was going nuts with this and this is what I have (check the edit).

Comment: The `freqz` is often used to visualize the frequency response of a discrete transfer function.  In this case the entire windowed signal is used rather than just the window.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe I misinterpreted your question but Matlab is not for continuous time analysis. It's for numerical analysis only, with discrete values. You can however calculate the discrete time fourier transform  (DFT) of your signal, the resolution of which will depend on the length of your signal. Are you using a Blackmann window because your signal is non-periodic?

How to calculate the FFT (DFT) in Matlab: http://www.mathworks.se/help/matlab/ref/fft.html

Any discrete Fourier transform will assume that your signal is periodic. If it isn't you will obtain spectral leakage where certain frequency peaks "leak" their energy to the sides resulting in less defined peak with smeared out frequency values. Thus, the time-domain signal is preferably made periodic before calculting the DFT - periodic to the extent that a general pattern is repeated, values does not have to exact between periods since noise can/will be inherent in the signal. Applying a window function to the time-domain signal before calculating the DFT will make the signal periodic but you will have change amplitude values and introduced a low frequency component.